# How to use a lambda as parameter in python argparse?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
help_f= "The Syntax is  lambda x: f(x), where f(x) is the function in python lenguage"
parser.add_argument("-f",dest="f", type=function, help=help_f, required=True)
params = parser.parse_args()
method( params.f)
```

I have something like this, the idea is that -f parameter to be a lambda. But i do not know how to do it when I called from a bash shell because if a try:

```
python archive.py -f lambda x: 2*x-4
```

I get error: "`error: argument -f: invalid function value: 'x : x-4'`"

Some help?

Comment: I don't reckon there's a good way to do this, but if you edit your question to explain why you want to, perhaps someone can suggest a better approach altogether.

Comment: As @JETM says, there's probably a better way to do this than passing in a Python lambda, but part of the problem is that the spaces in your command line are making the different parts of the function separate arguments. To make it one argument, try `python archive.py -f 'lambda x: 2*x-4`.

Comment: Allowing the user to specify arbitrary code to execute is generally a bad idea. It's also trivial to allow (although it's far more general): `add_argument("-f", type=eval)`. (You might argue that `eval` immediately executes it code, but the only reason to pass a function is to execute it eventually. Either way, your program will execute arbitrary code at some point.) The safer, though theoretically challenging, solution is to simply take a string as an argument, and validate it before calling `eval` on it.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. The idea is that I have to make a pythn script which has to run in shell. In this method I have to calculate values of a mathematical function.  If I  use chepner answer I can make simple expresion such as `python archive.py -f 'lambda x: 2*x-4` but I can not make things like  `python archive.py -f 'lambda x:  exp(x) - 4` even I have import math module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to access imported functions/modules you need to pass `globals` to `eval`. For example:

```
>>> from math import exp  # anything in global scope will be accessible
>>> lambda_t = 'lambda x: exp(x)'

>>> l = eval(lambda_t, globals())
>>> l(2)
7.38905609893065
```

To make this work as an argument, you would need to either accept a string and process it after, or wrap the creation of the lambda in another function. You can pass this as your `type` parameter to handle the conversion.

```
import argparse
from math import exp

def create_lambda_with_globals(s):
    return eval(s, globals())

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

help_f= "The Syntax is  lambda x: f(x), where f(x) is the function in python language"
parser.add_argument("-f",dest="f", type=create_lambda_with_globals, help=help_f, required=True)
params = parser.parse_args()  # the lambda is now defined in params.f

print(params.f(2))  # run the lambda with an input of 2
```

Running this from the command line:

```
python test.py -f 'lambda x: exp(x)'
7.38905609893
```